# string substitution using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

I have this string for example :

```
asddsa "ll" sadd " fsgsg"
"sdafaf" "lkkx" "fsgfgsg"
```

I want to substitute all characters inside `" "` with a character `x`. Expected output in this case should be:

```
asddsa "x" sadd " x"
    "x" "x" "x"
```

I tried something like this : `sed 's/".*"/"x"/g'` but the output is logically

`asddsa "x"
 "x"`

How could I fix my regexp to get the right output?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A dot `.` means *any* character.  But you don't want it to match a double quote; you want it to match anything *but* a double quote.  So specify that with a character class:

```
sed 's/"[^"]*"/"x"/g'
```